# Difference between ~ and -

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit, huffman-code

So I was messing around with Huffman coding and I noticed something I feel like I should have already known, but regretfully don't.

The thing in question is in the title and is concerned with this method:

```
void BinWriter::writeBit(bool b) {
    A ^= (-b^A)&(1UL << n++); // A is of type char

    if (n == 8) {
        ofd.write((char*)&A, 1);
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

If I write `~b` instead of `-b` the results are vastly different. Why is this? Isn't `~` suppose to be a negation operator? How does it differ from `-` in this case?

Also Visual Studio (2017) also warns me that both of these operators are 'unsafe' for bool types, why is this?

Comment: You can't apply `~` nor `-` to a bool in C/C++. So integer conversions and promotions are applied instead, turning your `bool` into an `int` (0 for false, 1 for true). It should be evident that applying `~` or `-` to those values now makes a huge difference. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: `~` is a `not` operator, not a negation operator.  It performs a *bitwise not* on the operand.  Look up bitwise not and it will explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling afoul of *integer promotion*. The not-very-scientific explanation is that for certain operators, if not explicitly defined, C++ will try to convert built-in integral types (including `bool`) to `int`. Then, that leads to the following results:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "~: " << ~true << ", " << ~false << "\n";
    std::cout << "-: " << -true << ", " << -false << "\n";
    std::cout << "!: " << !true << ", " << !false << "\n";
}
```

will print

```
~: -2, -1
-: -1, 0
!: false, true
```

Note how `!` is the only of these operators that is actually defined for `bool`, while the other two force integer promotion (with `false` turning into 0 and `true` into 1).

`-b^A` then means "keep all the bits the same way if `b` is `false`, and flip them all if `b` is `true`", while `~b^A` means "Flip all the bits all the time, but the last one only if `b` is `false`" - wholly different semantics!

Comment: Probably more advantageous to output those in hex (or even binary)